# Unhandled promise rejection. Can't connect to server

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, unhandled

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong here.I couldn't connect to the server and gives me a message that a promise was rejected and was not handled by catch(). Am i missing an async function somewhere? Thanks in advance.

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Dishes = require("./models/dishes");

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion";
const connect = mongoose.connect(url);

mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);
mongoose.set("useNewUrlParser", true);

connect.then(db => {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  var newDish = Dishes({
    name: "Uthappizza",
    description: "test"
  });

  newDish
    .save()
    .then(dish => {
      console.log(dish);

      return Dishes.find({});
    })
    .then(dishes => {
      console.log(dishes);

      return Dishes.remove({});
    })
    .then(() => {
      return mongoose.connection.close();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have no rejection handler on the promise from `mongoose.connect` itself (your `connect` constant). you only use `then`, not `catch`, and you don't supply the second argument to `then`.

Comment: The `catch()` you have, only catches rejects that happen in the promise chain starting at `newDish` but you never even reach that, because `connect` already throws.

Answer (score 0):

You have no rejection handler on the promise from `mongoose.connect` itself (your `connect` constant). you only use `then`, not `catch`, and you don't supply the second argument to `then`.

So the minimum change is:

```
connect.then(db => {
    // ...
})
.catch(error => {                            // ***
    // ...handle/report error connecting...  // ***
});                                          // ***
```

> Am i missing an async function somewhere?

No, but using one might make the code easier to follow (this is subjective). The purpose of `async`/`await` is to make it possible to write code with our usual flow-control structures while using promises.

For instance, if you can't use [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) or you don't want to, you could wrap all your code in an immediately-invoked `async` function like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Dishes = require("./models/dishes");

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion";

// If you can't use top level `await`, you can use an `async` IIFE
(async () => {
    const connect = await mongoose.connect(url);

    mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);
    mongoose.set("useNewUrlParser", true);

    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    var newDish = Dishes({
        name: "Uthappizza",
        description: "test"
    });

    const dish = await newDish.save();
    console.log(dish);
    const dishes = await Dishes.find({});
    console.log(dishes);

    await Dishes.remove({});
    await mongoose.connection.close();
})().catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

If you can use [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) and you want to (it does mean you have to switch to using [JavaScript's own module syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) instead of [CJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), but IMHO that's a good thing anyway), you can do this:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Dishes from "./models/dishes.js";

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion";

try {
    const connect = await mongoose.connect(url);

    mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);
    mongoose.set("useNewUrlParser", true);

    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    var newDish = Dishes({
        name: "Uthappizza",
        description: "test"
    });

    const dish = await newDish.save();
    console.log(dish);
    const dishes = await Dishes.find({});
    console.log(dishes);

    await Dishes.remove({});
    await mongoose.connection.close();
} catch (error) {
    // ...handle/report error...
}
```

Note, though, that you'd probably only want to do that in your top-level module (which it looks like this is), since it holds up resolution of the module tree. That's fine for the entry point module, or a module that can't create its exports until a promise settles, but for the logic in the code you've shown it would probably only be appropriate in the entry point module.